# Patch Columns in a SharePoint List using Dropdown in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, patch, powerapps-canvas

I have been doing a Canvas App where I puta a Dropdown associated to SharePoint List (1), that contains all the items that I would like to choose in one row each, this is intended to choose the right column for another SharePoint List (2). For this I want to put a value in a Text Input and Patch the SharePoint List (2), by using SharePoint List (1) as my Column and Text Input as my Value.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the names in the drop downs match your datasource names correctly you shouldn't have an issue achieving this.
Assuming below dropdown 2 is your sharepoint lists (2), Dropdown 1 is your column to patch (1) and TextInput1 is your value you wish to patch

```
Patch(Dropdown2.SelectedText.Value,Defaults(Dropdown2.SelectedText.Value),{Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value:TextInput1.Text})
```